# jQuery simple event which changes the icon on click and returns previous icon on next click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, navigation, toggle

I am trying to change the icon on click event by jQuery and return the previous icon while clicking again the same link. 
I have the navigation list which should open while clicking on link (with arrow-down icon) which should be changed for the arrow-up icon. Then when I click again it should return the arrow-up icon and close the navigation.

Here is some code. I don't know how to return first icon back on second click:

```js
$('.dropdown-nav').css('display', 'none');
$('.drop-arrow-up').css('display', 'none');

$('.house-build-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-nav').toggle();
  $('.fa-long-arrow-down').css('display', 'none');
  $('.drop-arrow-up').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="house-build-link">
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up drop-arrow-up"></i>
      House-renovation
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-nav">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should note that it's much better to use CSS to set the visibility of elements on initial page load. JS runs much later in the page lifecycle and can mean that elements are visible for a short period before being hidden.

To fix your actual issue you can simply just use `toggleClass` on the single `i` element. There's no need to show/hide different ones. Try this:

```js
$('.house-build-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-nav').toggle();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-long-arrow-down fa-long-arrow-up drop-arrow-up');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-nav { display: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="house-build-link">
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
      House-renovation
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-nav">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect, it is working. As always I have learned something new. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the hassle, you can do something like this. Have two icons inside and use CSS to hide and show them:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
  });
});
```

```css
a {display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center; font-size: 45px; text-decoration: none; color: #f33;}
/* Normal State */
a i.ion-checkmark-circled {display: none;}
/* Checked State */
a.checked {color: #f90;}
a.checked i.ion-checkmark-circled {display: inline;}
a.checked i.ion-close-circled {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
<a href="" class="button">
  <i class="ion-close-circled"></i>
  <i class="ion-checkmark-circled"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.house-build-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-nav').toggle();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-long-arrow-down fa-long-arrow-up drop-arrow-up');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-nav { display: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="house-build-link">
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
      House-renovation
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-nav">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="house-build-link">
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
      House-renovation
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-nav">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="house-build-link">
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
      House-renovation
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-nav">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```